# What is the explanation of the odd behaviour in the size of the array in the given code?

Tags: arrays, c, variable-length-array

```c
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int n;
    printf("Enter the number:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int array[n];

    for (int i=0;i<=n;i++){
        printf("%dEnter the number:",i);
        scanf("%d",&array[i]);
    }

    for (int i=n;i>=0;i--){
        printf("%d\n",array[i]);
    }
}
```

Where the size is defined to given number, but then the size is getting increased in while putting values inside the loop.
Expecting the array to be accepting only 5 values but it is accepting more than 5.

Comment: "Expecting the array to be accepting only 5 values but it is accepting more than 5." What would "accept" mean here? The array can hold 5 values. correct. You are writing 6 values. One of them doesn't go into the array but in memory you don't own. That's a bug in your program. If you expect that every bug immediately results into an error message, you are out of luck. That is not how C works.

Comment: Bug here: `i<=n`. Should be `i<n`.

Comment: You need to learn to count.  How many times does this loop iterate:  `for (int i=0;i<=n;i++){`  And how many times does this loop iterate:  `for (int i=n;i>=0;i--){`  Hint:  Neither of them iterates the desired `n` times.  Also, what do you think the largest valid index into `array` is?  Hint:  It's not `n`.

Answer (score 3):

1. The first loop writes to array `array[n]` out of bounds (loop executes n+1 times).  This is undefined behavior.  It will likely overwrite unrelated memory and often that cause a segfault.

   Arrays in C are 0 indexed so the first element is `array[0]` and the last is `array[n-1]`.

   The revised loop below is the standard idiom in C; if it's anything else a seasoned C developer will review it with extra care.
2. The 2nd loop read out of bound `array[n]` (n+1).  This is undefined behavior.
3. Check that n>=1 and reasonable size otherwise you program may crash running out of stack space.
4. Check the return value of `scanf()` otherwise you may be operating on uninitialized variables which is undefined behavior.
5. Formatted your code for readability (it matters).

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_N 100

int main(void) {
    int n;
    printf("Enter the number:");
    if(scanf("%d", &n) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "scanf() failed\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if(n <= 0 || n > MAX_N) {
        fprintf(stderr, "n is out of range\n");
        return 1;
    }
    int array[n];
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        printf("%dEnter the number:", i);
        if(scanf("%d", &array[i]) != 1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "scanf() failed\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }
    for(int i=n-1; i>=0; i--)
        printf("%d\n", array[i]);
}
```

example session:

```
Enter the number:3
0Enter the number:1
1Enter the number:2
2Enter the number:3
3
2
1
```

Comment: Re “This is undefined behavior which means anything can happen…”: That is not the meaning of “undefined behavior.”

Comment: @EricPostpischil "behavior, upon use of a nonportable or erroneous program construct or of erroneous data, for which this International Standard imposes no requirements" so how is that different from anything can happen?  I am happy to revise the answer of course.

Comment: When the standard says it does not impose any requirements, that does not enable things that cannot happen to happen. So it does not mean anything can happen. It does not enable user programs to violate operating system constraints. It does not enable processors to violate hardware designs (e.g., a program with behavior the C standard does not define is not allowed to set the computer on fire, because that constraint comes from other requirements, not from the C standard). Further, this difference is important for debugging…

Comment: … If undefined behavior meant “anything can happen,” then it would be exceedingly difficult to debug programs. There are often logical connections between types of bugs and types of observed behavior. Overflowing an `int` in a calculation does not directly cause a segment fault, but overflowing an array bound may. Saying “anything can happen” sends the wrong message that you cannot reason about program behavior when it is not defined by the C standard. But you can reason about it because it is defined and affected by other factors.

Comment: A correct statement here is that writing to `array[n]` out of bounds “is not defined by the C standard, and it is not guarded against by the compiler, and it can overwrite other data in program memory or can cause an access violation (segment fault).” Those are limited things, not any things; it will not overwrite data in other programs, and it will not cause a fire.

Comment: @EricPostpischil While I appreciate the finer point of what you are trying to say... behavior remains undefined.  It may segfault, it may not, compiler may guard against it and it may not.

Comment: Yes, it can cause a segment fault. And telling readers that is fine. But students do not know these things at first, and what they are told matters. It takes time to learn how memory protection works on multiuser systems and how compilers and linkers and program loaders all work and what patterns of behavior they produce and how those can be used to make deductions and debug. To learn those things, students have to be given correct statements. Telling them “anything can happen” leads them down the wrong path, away from deductive reasoning. It makes it harder for them to learn the right rules.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I toned it down.  Hopefully it appeased.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `i` will be equal `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5`. Just count the numbers, there are 6 of them. That is why body of for-loop is executed more than 5 times.

It is very common to write
`for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) // ...`
if you want this for-loop to work `n` times.